# Abort a connection after sending request in fiddler

Tags: fiddler

In fiddler we have got methods like **OnBeforeRequest** and **OnBeforeResponse** . I want to drop a connection after the request is sent to the server. I don't want to retrieve the response from server. Currently I am using the following code which I found on this site under the OnBeforeResponse to abort a connection. But in *Fiddler's WebView* I can see the response sent from the server which means fiddler is downloading the contents but not sending it to the client.

```
if (oSession.uriContains("http://example.com")) {
        oSession.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseCode = 0;
        oSession.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseStatus = "0 Client Connection Dropped by script";
        oSession.state = SessionStates.Aborted;
    }
```

I want to drop the connection after it is sent to server in something like **OnAfterRequest** method to immediately abort the connection after it has been sent and not load the contents even in Fiddler's WebView but I have not found something like that.Is it possible? Can anyone point me to the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why, specifically, would you want to do this?

Your code sample will not do what you want; it will read the response from the server, then kill the connection to the client.

In Fiddler, the only way you can kill the server connection after sending the request is to kill the connection inside the `oSession.OnStateChanged` event, when `SessionStates.ReadingResponse` is entered. However, this almost certainly has side-effects that you're not expecting.

Comment: Thank for replying . I want to make a script that needs to send multiple  request to the server and are fast enough . Also I don't want to download the response in my case for confirmation because I don't have to operate on the downloaded data , it will decrease my bandwidth usage and increase the speed of request. Can you show me a little snippet of what you have suggested . And what kind of side-effects can I expect from this.  Thank you

Comment: The proper way to handle your scenario is to send a `HEAD` request to the server instead of a `GET` request.

Comment: `HEAD` is an alternative for `GET` request but I am sending forms to server in `POST` request . I think it's not possible to send post data in HEAD request . Please correct me if I am wrong. Can you suggest me any way to put my codes within `OnStateChanged` event. I am unable to find the event in Fiddler's script (Rules ---.> Customize rules). It would be a great help to me. Thank you.

Comment: How much data does the target return? Setting up a connection is often the slowest part of the web, so killing a perfectly good connection to avoid downloading on it is often a false economy.

Comment: Actually I don't need to operate on the confirmation message sent by the server as it is the very last step of the script (it is a vb script) that needs to send multiple around 30 asynch POST requests  at the same time and don't need any connection to reuse as it would be of no use. So I was thinking if it was possible to send data to the server ,then just acknowledge that the server received the full post data then abort that connection so that my asynch request will go fast. Its actually the time which I want to save and the bandwidth usage is secondary. So if possible help me. Thanks

Comment: Is it not possible or I am missing something?